# How can I set a vote on the comments?

Tags: blog, support

In this wordpress [blog](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/mini-polymath3-discussion-thread/#comment-58454), one can vote the comments. I am wondering how can I set up this function in my wordpress blog?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your blog is self-hosted, the easiest way to add a comment voting system is to install a plugin (e.g. [Comment Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-rating/)).

If your blog is on WordPress.com, then you'd need to go through the options the options on WordPress.com to see where you could enable that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Mine is the second case. Now I see.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Manzabar's answer, I solve the problem as the following picture shows:
[image]